# Testing Google recaptcha on local server, returns "Error: Invalid domain for site key"

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

I am developing a mobile based web application and need to test it from a mobile browser while my test-server is hosted on a machine in my local network. I use google-recaptcha on login.

But as google recaptcha only supports "127.0.0.1" and I use the local IP address in my browser URL bar (i.e. http://192.168.1.120:8080/#/login), it returns the following error:

> Error: Invalid domain for site key

Answer (score 1):

You can manage list of domains for each ReCaptcha key. : https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list

In ReCaptcha Key Settings, you must add "192.168.1.20" to your key.

PS : Also, I've seen some people say that by recreating the key it worked

Comment: Yes, for some reason I found I had to regenerate the keys after I added a new domain